# How to add capabilties to the LXC container

Tags: lxc

I found that to run a blocked system call( like ptrace) inside a lxc container
the capabilities need to be added. How exactly the capabilities can be added to the lxc container.

Comment: I want to know how to add capability for ptrace system call inside the lxc

Answer (score -1):

you can use lxc.keep.cap or lxc.drop.cap in container config. See man 7 capabilities and /usr/share/lxc/config/*.conf files